# Using glm win disease percentage

Tags: regression

I have plant disease percentages (I have evaluated the % of diseased tissue). My percentages go from 0 (no symptom) to 100 %.
I did an ANOVA but a linear model seems not valid for proportions.

So, I wish to fit a GLM on them to explore how different my genotypes and treatments affect the development of the disease.

I do not know if I have to choose Binomial, Quasibinomial as I have arbitrary proportions and not proportions that were calculated from the size of my population. 
I read that betareg may be used but as I have 0s and 1s it is not working.

I do not know if among these choices, one is the good one to answer my questions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: or you can adjust the 0/1 values slightly toward the center of the range (see e.g. Verkuilen and ?'s "better lemon squeezer" paper on beta regression ...)

Comment: Beta regression comes with 0 and 1-inflated flavours that might work in your setting. See here for a quick introduction: https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/zero-one-inflated-beta-models-for-proportion-data/. The zoib package in R could come in handy: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015/RJ-2015-019/RJ-2015-019.pdf.

Comment: I moved my comment after Ben's, as I wanted to add a couple of links to it and couldn't unless I deleted it.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks a lot. I will try and let you know

Comment: @IsabellaGhement I tried, but I have many errors or warnings. So maybe I will need some clarification. I am not a statistician and the model seems quite complicated. I have data with genotypes (character), treatment (character) and my plant disease percentages (from 0 included to 1 included) corresponding to my response variable. But I strictly don’t understand how to write my model! I tried: model <- zoib(disease~genotype|treatment, data = data) Error in fixed01(y[, i], n, xmu.1, p.xmu, xsum.1, p.xsum, x0.1, p.x0, : object 'x0.1' not found Can someone help me ? Thanks

Comment: First thing I would do is to convert genotype and treatment to factors in R using the as.factor() or factor() function. A factor is basically R's way of handling categorical variables. When R encounters a factor in the model, it automatically creates dummy variables behind the scenes when fitting the model, which will capture the effect of the categorical variable. You should also choose the reference level/category for each factor to be something meaningful against which all other levels will be compared. The relevel() function will be handy for this.

Comment: Are you interested in investigating how genotype and treatment (treated as factors) affect the probability of getting the disease? Do you suspect that these two factors interact in their effect? Then you should presumably fit a model like model <- zoib(disease~genotype*treatment, data = data). This model postulates that the effect of treatment on the probability of getting the disease may depend on the genotype. The * symbol denotes the interaction between genotype and treatment.

Comment: If you wanted instead to fit a model where the effect of treatment on the probability of getting the disease is independent of genotype, you would use a syntax like model <- zoib(disease ~ genotype + treatment, data = data).

Comment: Given your background, I think the zoib model may indeed be too complicated for you to work with. It might be easier for you to pursue Ben's suggestion. Keep us posted! 

Comment: Oops! Please replace everywhere in my comment "probability of getting the disease" with  "a nonlinear transformation of the (true) percentage of diseased plants".  Thanks!

Comment: @IsabellaGhement. I tried what you said : converting genotype and treatment infactors and then I did this > model <- zoib(racine2~genotype+traitement, 
+             data = data)
Error in zoib(racine2 ~ genotype + traitement, data = data) : 
  please re-specify the model
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In zoib(racine2 ~ genotype + traitement, data = data) :
  The right side of the model should have at least two parts;

Comment: 2: In zoib(racine2 ~ genotype + traitement, data = data) :
  or two link functions, one for the mean of beta distribution
3: In zoib(racine2 ~ genotype + traitement, data = data) :
  alpha/(alpha+beta) and one for the sum (alpha+beta)

Comment: Here are the errors...

Answer (score 2):

Guillaume, if you are willing to stick with the zoib package, you will find more details about how to specify a zoib model at http://127.0.0.1:13951/library/zoib/html/zoib.html.

In particular, note that you will need to specify the right hand side of the model much more carefully.  Perhaps you could start out with something like this:

```
model <- zoib(racine2 ~ genotype + traitement|genotype|traitement|1,
              joint = FALSE, 
              zero.inflation = TRUE, 
              one.inflation = TRUE, 
              random = 0, 
              EUID = 1:nrow(data),  
              link.mu = "logit", 
              link.x0 = "logit", 
              link.x1 = "logit", 
              data = data)
```

In the above, **joint = FALSE** signals that you are modelling a single response variable, racine2. Because this response variable has a distribution which exhibits both zero and one inflation, you need to set **zero.inflation = TRUE** and **one.inflation = TRUE**.

Since your model does not include any random effects, you need to set **random = 0**.

The **EUID** refers to the experimental unit ID so you can just set the IDs to be 1, 2, 3 and so on until n, where n represents the number of observations in your data set.

Since mu denotes the mean of the Beta distribution, link.mu denotes the link function applied to this mean to facilitate its modeling.  By default, **link.mu = "logit"**.  Other options for link.mu include **link.mu = "probit"** and **link.mu = "cloglog"**.

While zoib does not explicitly include a link function for eta, where eta is the sum of the two shape parameters of the Beta distribution, it seems to use a log link function behind the scenes.

There is also a link function used for modelling **p0 = Pr(y=0)** which is called link.x0, where y denotes the response variable.  By default, **link.x0 = "logit"**.

Finally, there is a link function used for modelling **p1 = Pr(y=1|y>0)** which is called link.x1.  **link.x1 = "logit"**.

The construct **genotype + traitement|genotype|traitement|1* which appears on the right hand side of the zoib model formula can be a bit confusing, as it allows you to simultaneously model different things.

The way I understand it - and perhaps someone on this forum can confirm if my understanding is correct - when you have a zero-one inflated response variable, you are going to break down its modelling into 3 different components.  This will allow you to model separately:

1. The values of y for which y is in (0,1);
2. The values of y for which y = 0;
3. The values of y for which y = 1 (given that y was NOT 0 and also not in (0,1)).

For 1., you are going to assume that y follows a Beta distribution and model its mean (i.e., mu) as well as the sum of the two shape parameters (i.e., eta) of the Beta distribution as a function of the available predictors.  The mean of Beta and the sum of its two shape parameters are transformed via the link functions specified in the zoib model call. If that call includes a construct such as
**genotype + traitement|genotype|traitement|1**, that means that:

```
logit(mu) = beta0 + beta1*genotype + beta2*traitement
```

and

```
log(eta) = delta0 + delta1*genotype.
```

(Here, I am assuming that both genotype and treatment have only two levels each so that I can explicitly specify the models being used for mu and eta, without the need to include dummy variables to code the effect of genotype and treatment).
In other words, logit(mu) depends linearly on the predictors listed first in the construct and log(eta)

For 2., using the same construct **genotype + traitement|genotype|traitement|1** means that you will model the following:

```
logit(p0) = gamma0 + gamma1*treatment
```

where recall that p0 = Pr(y=0), while for 3., you will model:

```
logit(p1) = epsilon0
```

where p1 = Pr(y=1|y>0).

While this is not clear from the link I provided above, I believe that mu represents the mean of y *given the predictors which are used to model it*. Similarly, Pr(y=0) represents the probability that y = 0 *given the predictors that are used to model this probability*, while Pr(y=1|y>0) is also a conditional probability that y = 1 given y > 0 and given the predictors that are used to model this probability. (In my example above, none of the predictors are actually used to model Pr(y=1|y>0), so that the probability is constant regardless of the values of the available predictors.)

Note that zoib can take a while to fit your model. When done, you can just type:

```
model
```

at the R console to see what comes out.  You can then use R code like the one below to interrogate the model:

```
# model summary 
sample1 <- model$coeff
sample1

summary(sample1)

# check convergence of the MCMC chains
traceplot(sample1)
autocorr.plot(sample1) 
gelman.diag(sample1)

# posterior inferences from zoib
summ1 <- summary(sample1)
summ1
summ2 <- cbind(summ1$stat[, 1], summ1$quant[, c(1, 5)])
summ2
```

In the summ1 output, results will be presented for logit(mu) first, then log(eta), then logit(p0) and finally for logit(p1).  The summ2 object will show only selected output from the summ1 object, namely the posterior mean and the Bayesian credible interval for each of the parameters from the fitted zoib model.  You could try plotting the posterior means and credible intervals like so:

```
paraplot(summ2, legpos = "topright", annotate=TRUE, legtext = c("zoib"))
```

though the paraplot function needs some further rewrites to produce a quality publication plot.  Please refer back to https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015/RJ-2015-019/RJ-2015-019.pdf for more details.

Addendum:

It is possible to also fit a zero one inflated beta regression using the **gamlss** package, as follows:

```
install.packages("gamlss")
install.packages("gamlss.dist")

require(gamlss)
require(gamlss.dist)

model.gamlss <- gamlss(racine2 ~ genotype + traitement, 
                sigma.formula=~genotype, 
                nu.formula=~traitement, 
                tau.formula=~1,
                family=BEINF)

summary(model.gamlss)

GAIC(model.gamlss)
```

The convenience of gamlss is that it fits the model using a frequentist rather than a Bayesian framework.  It also allows for model comparison using the 
GAIC() function - this comes in handy in terms of trying various options for 
mu.formula, sigma.formula, nu.formula and tau.formula and seeing which option is best supported by the data. However, you must make sure you understand how gamlss parametrizes the model and what link functions it uses for each model component. See, for example, https://rdrr.io/cran/gamlss.dist/man/BEINF.html, for more insights into the parametrization used by gamlss (you need to look under the heading **Details**).

The gamlss package also comes with a term.plot() function which can be used to visualize the effects of the predictors on each of the modelled components:

```
term.plot(model.gamlss, what = "mu")
term.plot(model.gamlss, what = "sigma")
term.plot(model.gamlss, what = "nu")
term.plot(model.gamlss, what = "tau")
```

Diagnostic plots for model.gamlss can be obtained with functions such as:

```
plot(model.gamlss)
```

The worm plot for model.gamlss can be obtained with

```
wp(model.gamlss)
```

and the Q-statistics plot can be obtained with

```
Q.stats(model.gamlss).
```

You can search for the document *"Instructions on how to use the gamlss package in R Second Edition"* on Google for more info on gamlss.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your time. I will try to do my best and I'll let you know !

Comment: Fingers crossed, Guillaume!  Don't forget there is always the option provided by Ben (shifting the 0 and 1 proportions away from 0 and 1, respectively and then modelling all proportions via beta regression), which is much simpler though not entirely faithful to the nature of the data. 

Comment: It is really difficult for me to understand the meaning of the results of either zoib  or gamlss models... even the plots are difficult to understand. I am not a statistician at all. An ANOVA seems totally easier with significant codes...

Comment: Yes, working with proportions is not the easiest of tasks, especially if you have lots of values such as 0 and/or 1 in your data. If you have just a few such values, you can use the transform suggested by Ben first but then you would still need to use something like beta regression. The problem with ANOVA or linear regression is that they are not set up to acknowledge that proportions are naturally bounded between 0 and 1, which means model diagnostics may be way off.

Comment: Can't I use a quasi-binomial model using glm ? Why a beta regression ?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement the first link is down. Can you help us with an update?